# Angular Chain HTTP is causing errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying the following code in an angular.js application to migrate data from one database to another.  This is one part of the function in order to gain authorization credentials to send POSTs to the receiving database.  However, it doesn't work.  My first function, `ATsintegrationsService.beginBackfill(clientIDs)`, returns the list of applicants fine.  The error begins at `getAuthToken()`.  Even though it hits the URL with the correct data, I keep on getting an error in the service.  Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here, I'd really appreciate it.  I'm at a loss for what may be causing my issues.

Main function (triggered by hitting an apply button):

```
$scope.beginBackfill = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    AtsintegrationsService.beginBackfill($scope.clientids).then(function (response) {
       $scope.applicants = response.data;
       $scope.getAuthToken();
       $scope.createSuccess = true;
       $scope.loading = false;
     },
       function(error) {
          $scope.loading = false;
          $scope.createFailure = true;
          console.log("Failure to backfill data - " + error);
       });
   };
```

Here is `$scope.getAuthToken()`:

```
$scope.getAuthToken = function() {
    AtsintegrationsService.getAuthToken().then(function (response) {
        $scope.authToken = response.data;
        console.log($scope.authToken);
    },
    function(error) {
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.createFailure = true;
        console.log("Failure to obtain auth token - " + error);
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

And finally, the service code for `getAuthToken()` - some data has been removed and is indicated by `{snip}`.

```
srvc.getAuthToken = function () {
var url = {snip};

return $http({
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    responseType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data:
    {
        "grant_type": "{snip}",
        "client_id": {snip},
        "client_secret": "{snip}"
    }
})
  .success(function (data) {
    console.log("We have a proper return.");
    return data;
  })
  .error(function (data) {
    console.log("There was an error in the service.");
    return data;
  });
 };
```

Comment: Is that getAuthToken service at `url = {snip}` perhaps using OAuth 1 or 2? What grant_type is used?

Comment: grant_type = client_credentials

I have tested the route in Postman and it works fine.  But, when I do the same "stuff" in my code, all I get are the error console.logs.

EDIT:  Also, adding that OAuth 2 is being used.

Comment: Ok, just took a peek at postman, and the only options there are to add the tokens either to the URL or to the HTTP headers. I don't know how that service is implemented (server-side), and what it accepts, but maybe you need send the fields in `data: {..}` as GET parameters in the URL.

Comment: Why would it work in my Postman as a POST sending the `data: {..}` I have, but not here?  Sorry, not following why that would fix my issue since I have successful Postman API returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out the problem was with CORS headers; the code I have was fine.